# Getting touches for a view with subview

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiview, touch

i want to have a top view (subclass of UIView), which catches touches using

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
...
```

.h

```
@interface XView : UIView<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) UITableView * tableView;

@end
```

this works fine, if the view is empty, but as soon as i insert (addSubview) lets say a UITableView

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame 
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code

        self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame];

        self.tableView.delegate = self;
        self.tableView.dataSource = self;

        [self addSubview:self.tableView];

    }
    return self;
}
```

Than the touch methods inside XView are not triggered

Answer (score 0):

You would either need to subclass your UITableView or use a UITapGestureRecognizer to solve this.  I'd personally go with the UITapGestureRecognizer.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapCode:)];
[self.tableView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

and then you can handle your tap here:

```
- (void)tapCode:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    // code goes here
}
```

If you subclass UITableView, you can put your touchesBegan:withEvent in there.